# set constrains in a liner model using R

Tags: r

I am trying to predict future market share using the following linear model.

```
    x <- c(20, 60, 80,130)
    y <- c(0.8, 0.15,0.05, 0.0)
    z <-data.frame(x, y)
    z.fit <- lm(y~x, data=z)
    z.prediction <- predict(z.fit, data.frame(x=c(30, 65, 70, 100)), interval="prediction")
```

The results are above 1, see below:

```
      fit
    1 0.544
    2 0.301
    3 0.267
    4 0.059
```

How can I set a constrain in the code for sum of "Share" =1?

Comment: Have you tried just adjusting your results. Seems abit lazy but if you only need to adjust for market share this may work? May help, not sure on your use.    
a <- as.vector(z.prediction[1:4,1])
a/sum(a)

Answer (score 1):

The question did not define *Share* but assuming it is the fitted values, try the CVXR package.  Note that a nonnegativity constraint has been added but you can drop it if negative values are acceptable.

```
library(CVXR)

b <- Variable(2)
pred <- b[1] + b[2] * x

objective <- Minimize(sum((y - pred)^2))
constraints <- list(sum(pred) == 1, pred >= 0)
problem <- Problem(objective, constraints)
soln <- solve(problem)

bval <- soln$getValue(b)

bval
##              [,1]
## [1,]  0.565217391
## [2,] -0.004347826

# check constraints

predval <- soln$getValue(pred)
round(predval, 5)
##         [,1]
## [1,] 0.47826
## [2,] 0.30435
## [3,] 0.21739
## [4,] 0.00000

sum(predval)
## [1] 1
```

Comment: The code worked with my data. Thank you so much for your help.